# How can I suppress warnings for using '!!' (not not)?

Tags: javascript, jshint

In my project jshint complains about `!!` I need to convert a string to a boolean value

```
var x = 'true';
if ( !!x === true ) { ... }
```

So, jshint throws the following problem:

```
line 35  col 20  Confusing use of '!'.
```

What jshint-option should I disable to allow this? Or is that not possible?

Comment: if you wrote `x='false'` it will still come back truthy. I'm not sure what you mean by trying to convert the string into a boolean. I believe !! just validates that x isn't falsey in itself.

Comment: Don't; this kind of _cute_ code is exactly what `jshint` is trying to prevent.

Comment: The actual problem was that `x` could be a boolean value or `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with `===`. Simply

```
if (!!x )
```

works fine.

I think the "confusing" part is that  `!!foo === bar` is hard to parse priority-wise (is it `(!!foo)==bar` or `!(!foo==bar)`?).

Comment: True, in my situation it was !!x !== true :) I changed it to: `!!x ^ true` and now it works and jshint is happy!

Comment: !!x will always be true if x has a value it will eval to true. so !!"false" == true

Answer (score 4):

This particular "feature" has caused so much pain in the community.
You can disable it by putting this in your .jshintrc config file.

```
{
    "-W018":  true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WARNING: this is not going to evaluate the way you want it to

```
var myBool = Boolean("false");  // == true

var myBool = !!"false";  // == true
```

if you don't want jshint to yell at you, also you don't need to have === when comparing bool == is the same. though if you are making a bool value you should not need to compare it at all.

```
if(myBool)
{
    //some code here
}
```

or

```
if(!myBool)
{
    //some code here
}
```

to get the value as a bool you prob want to just do a string comparison

```
var mybool = aString == "true";
```

that should get you what you are looking for then you can just:

```
if(myBool)
{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: when I do: `var x = Boolean('false')` the value of `x` is **true**

Answer (score 0):

To really answer this question, not providing workarounds, disabling this error in jshint can be done by

**-W018**

Comment: Please edit the answer to explain what to do with the bolded text.

Comment: The question has been what is the jshint-option to disable and the option is the code W018 and where to use it depends on how you use jshint.

Using jshin grunt implementation you can add it in the setup of grunt, while you also can just add a comment in the code just before the line to ignore using `/* jshint -W018 */`, but from the question that was already known by the one who asked and is part of their documentation...
https://jshint.com/docs/